# Passing parameterized query list of int's returns error ora-01722

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle, ora-01722

Using the oledb provider.  Query is something like this:

```
SELECT appid 
  FROM table 
 WHERE response_id IN (?)
```

I take an int array and send it to a method that adds a comma delimiter between the array values, and returns a string. This string is then sent as the parameter.

This works fine if I have one value to pass through, but when I send two values I get the `ORA-01722` error.

I've tried looking at the `v_$sql` table to see what's being executed, but it's not showing queries executed by my page. I can only see things I executed via toad, even though I'm using the same login in both cases. Not sure if there are other tables that store sql data.

The string builder is below.

```
public string intArrayToString(int[] array)
{
    if (array != null)
    {
        string delimiter = ",";

        if (array.Length > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            builder.Append(array[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                builder.Append(delimiter);
                builder.Append(array[i]);
            }                    
            return builder.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle stored procedure with parameters for IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242771/oracle-stored-procedure-with-parameters-for-in-clause)

Comment: This link might be of value as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541466/oracleparameter-and-in-clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just put a comma-separated string as the `IN` value unfortunately. What you can do is automatically generating a bind variable for each of the array elements and binding each value, like so:

```
select appid from table where response_id in (:id1, :id2, :id3)
```

Comment: Doing that I'd have to have two loops each time this type of query was executed, one for updating the sql string and another to loop through the int array and add parameters. I was hoping there was a cleaner solution.

Comment: @Jarek: Unfortunately I know of no cleaner solution. That said, for the DB access layer we use at work I wrote the code in such a fashion that I just put the query as `... IN (:myParam)` and then while adding the parameters (which also happens through an own method) I detect if the parameter value is an array and automatically rewrite the query to `... IN (:myParam1, :myParam2, myParam3)` and fill the values.

Comment: @Jarek: SerViver is correct - there is no SQL supports a variable that contains a comma separated list as an `IN` parameter.  It requires using dynamic SQL to support what you ask for - either in the application, or SQL.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, you can have a variable that is a collection of numbers so there are other ways to solve this than dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

Which driver to you use to connect to Oracle? Here two different odp.net solutions: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=892457&tstart=810

edit: I see that you use the oledb provider. I guess that limits the possibilities? (I've never used that provider so I don't know). Maybe it is time to switch?