# OracleParameter and IN Clause with array of strings

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, odp.net

Sorry for this bad question.
I found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/541706/5417285
But I don't know how to inject list of string to here.
I created TABLE type in database and edited code:

```
 OracleParameter param = new OracleParameter("CATEGID", categoryIds.ToArray())
            {
                OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
            };
            OracleParameter[] oracleParams = new OracleParameter[1];
            oracleParams[0] = param;

            string queryStr = "SELECT * FROM T_OP_OTMT WHERE TRIM (CATEGID) IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE (T_VARCHAR2_OPMT (:CATEGID)))";
```

But get error ORA-01484.

Please help me, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Shouldn't your "categid" variable be just a string of elements? rather than an array itself?

Comment: It is an array of list CategIds